# PHP preg_replace remove all dot character from between square brackets

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

How do I remove all `.` characters from between two square brackets in a string using preg_replace?

I'm trying to replace only between square brackets and not other dots in the string. This should have worked, but somehow just gives a blank string. How do I write the regex for this?

```
$str = '[city.name][city.state][city.mayor][city.mayor.name](city.name)';
$str = preg_replace('/\[.*?\]/','',$str);
echo $str;
// output
[cityname][citystate][citymayor][citymayorname](city.name)
```

Comment: :-) What the right term for it?

Comment: @SaadSuri: There might have been a reason why someone downvoted your answer - it's too simple, really, and will match dots outside of `[` and `]` as well (which might not be be what OP wants). Additionally, a dot does not need to be escaped within a character class - `[.]` will totally do.

Comment: @Jan Oh sorry didn't read that part thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `\G` as in

```
(?:\G(?!\A)|\[)
[^\].]*\K\.
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/yaBuzs/1/) (mind the verbose mode).

---

Broken down, this says:

```
(?:
    \G(?!\A)     # match after the previous match (not the start)
    |            # or
    \[           # [
)
[^\].]*          # neither dot nor ]
\K               # make the engine forget what's been matched before
\.               # match a dot
```

Comment: Can a closing `]` be added? So it only works with text between a `[` & `]`Right now it replacing even other `.` in the string...

Comment: Ok. Your solution works fine. What would I need to change if needed it to match angular brackets?

Answer (score 2):

You may use

```
'~(?:\G(?!^)|\[)[^][.]*\K\.~' # For [strings]
'~(?:\G(?!^)|<)[^<>.]*\K\.~'  # For <strings>
```

Or, to make sure there is a close `]` there, add a `(?=[^][]*])` lookahead:

```
'~(?:\G(?!^)|\[)[^][.]*\K\.(?=[^][]*])~' # For [strings]
'~(?:\G(?!^)|<)[^<>.]*\K\.(?=[^<>]*])~'  # For <strings>
```

See [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/slU53H/2) and a [regex demo with lookahead](https://regex101.com/r/KAtwdS/1).

**Details**

- `(?:\G(?!^)|\[)` - a `[` or end of the previous successful match
- `[^][.]*` - any 0+ chars other than `[`, `]` and `.`
- `\K` - match reset operator
- `\.` - a dot
- `(?=[^][]*])` - a positive lookahead that requires a `]` after any 0+ chars other than `]` and `[` immediately to the right of the current location.

[PHP demo](https://ideone.com/gxfAy0):

```
$str = '[city.name][city.state][city.mayor][city.mayor.name](city.name)';
echo preg_replace('~(?:\G(?!^)|\[)[^][.]*\K\.~', '', $str);
```

Comment: How can this be modified to match angular brackets? Works fine for `[` & `]`but I'm struggling to get it to work with `<` and `>`

Comment: @Norman Both `[...]` and `<...>`? Or two separate patterns? If your values cannot contain `<`, `>`, `[` and `]`, use [`'~(?:\G(?!^)|\[|<)[^][<>.]*\K\.~'`](https://regex101.com/r/slU53H/3). As those values are identifiers, I think that this solution will work.

Comment: Two separate patterns. I'll be using one preg_replace for the square brackets and another for angular brackets.

Comment: @Norman If those are indentifiers, [you may replace all `[^<>.]*` / `[^][.]*` with a mere `\w*`](https://regex101.com/r/slU53H/4)

Answer (score 1):

Use callback

```
$str = preg_replace_callback('/\[[^]]*\]/', function($m){
    return str_replace(".", "", $m[0]);
}, $str);
```